# Data binding to the output of a method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to display the output of a method in a WPF `TextBox`. I'm just trying a simple attempt, to print a single string `3` in a `TextBox`.

I'm trying to do it the following way, using an `ObjectDataProvider`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataprovider" ObjectType="{x:Type system:String}" MethodName="GetValue">

        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataprovider}, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="201,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here's my code behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string GetValue()
        {
            return "3";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting no output. the `TextBox` is just blank. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `ObjectDataProvider` create a property like this:

```
public string GetMethod
{
     get
     {
         return GetValue();
     }
}
```

And:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this;
}
```

Then in the XAML remove `ObjectDataProvider` and just:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding GetMethod, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Height="23" Margin="201,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```